# JQuery attributes & strings

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a tool that allows me to retrieve thumbnails from YouTube when provided with the video ID.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $("#get-thumbnail").click(function() {
        $('#thumbnail').text("<img src='http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + $('#video-id').val() + "/maxresdefault.jpg'>");
    }
});
```

The current JS doesn't seem to work and I can't see the issue?

Comment: You are missing ');' on the second last line.

Comment: What is it supposed to do, and what is it doing instead>

Comment: also since you are using the img tag, you should use .html instead of .text

Comment: And use `$(document.ready()`, not `$(window).load()`.

Comment: Thank you! Should've noticed that error, as for the html - will try that now, cheers.

Comment: @BArmar in fact just `$(function(){....});` will bind on document ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.html()` insted of `.text()` because you're inserting a new tag. Also, you have add an `);` to close your click function in the previous last line.